# How do I launch manually installed applications?

Tags: package-management

I'm completely new to Ubuntu. I'm used to being able to execute the .exe file in Windows. But in here, when I click on a file that looks to be a start up, it doesn't work. I'm using Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi 2.

I typed

```
sudo chmod +r+x ZSNES
```

It said that zsnes was not a filename. ZSNES is an SNES emulator. I have all the extracted files in a folder on my desktop. I tried putting the directory in place of the file, put the extension at the end, other stuff. Usually I'm not this bad with technology. But when it comes to Linux, I'm really bad. Here's a [Dropbox link to the archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/634pipblt2g3kli/zsnes151src.tar.bz2?dl=0), if you want to see for yourself on how it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal using the shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+T** 
Type the name of the application and press enter.
If you need admin/root priviledges, use the prefix *sudo* followed by the name of the application. 
Example -

sudo bash *filename*

Also .exe files dont run on Linux directly. If you want to run .exe file , install the Wine platform.
For applications in Linux, you need .deb package.

Comment: Software that I'm trying to run, I downloaded from my PC to a flash drive, and all the programs come in archives. I extracted them, but the file that looks to be executable brings up an error.

Comment: use the command **sudo chmod +r+x *Filename*** to make the file executable.

Comment: I'll try.I just can't connect my Pi to the internet because I have no HDMI monitors. I only have a giant flat screen, and I'm not moving that near the modem. I can't go to Ubuntu's store because of that.

Comment: well , application installation in ubuntu is much easier by downloading the application directly from the repository, but  you can download the .deb file as well, but there is a incompatibility factor present and a possibility of the program being buggy

Comment: Ok. I'd tried that. I typed "sudo chmod +r+x ZSNES". It said that zsnes was not a filename. ZSNES is an SNES emulator. I have all the extracted files in a folder on my desktop. I tried putting the directory in place of the file, put the extension at the end, other stuff. Usually I'm not this bad with technology. But when it comes to Linux, I'm really bad. I can send you a Dropbox link to the archive, if you want to see for yourself on how it executes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/634pipblt2g3kli/zsnes151src.tar.bz2?dl=0

Comment: @RandomStalker135: this information should go into an edit to your question, as I did for you. Comments may not be read or they may be deleted any time.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the installation procedure for your mentioned package :
You'll also need :
- SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) : check http://www.libsdl.org to grab SDL 1.2.0 or
                                   later. 
- NASM v0.98.39 : http://nasm.sf.net/
- zlib v1.2.3 or higher : http://www.zlib.net
                                   it is probably already installed on your
                                   system, maybe you are just missing the
                                   development headers. Check in the
                                   packages available with your distribution
                                   or go to the page above
- libpng : http://www.libpng.org/
                    You might also need libpng, ZSNES will compile without
                    PNG support but I have found doing so to make ZSNES
                    unstable for some weird reason.  If you don't have
                    libpng, either get it and install it or pass the
                    --without-png option to the 'configure' script. 
- Curses/NCurses
             Check your distro. One of these is needed if you compile with
             the debugger enabled. You may also have to symlink ncurses.h
             to curses.h in your include directory.

Then to build the executable, go to the src directory and type:

```
sudo sh ./autogen.sh && gmake && gmake install
```

Note: This only covers SVN/WIP builds, for releases see instructions below.

Note: autogen.sh requires automake and autoconf installed. Any parse errors
you recieve about configure.in are due to those not being installed.

Also Note: libpng (optional) needs to be recent, or zsnes will not use it. 
Src :  **zsnes_1_51/docs/install.txt**

Comment: This would probbly be a whole lot easier if I had access to the store, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's true. But , in this case , please check the compatible version and download the dependencies.

Comment: Nevermind. I have Internet now.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the question is the source code, you can't run it, you must build it.

You would almost certainly face dependence issues and as you have no Internet connection on your Ubuntu this will be a big problem.

Instead you should use a `.deb` file, you will need to download them somehow of course and put it in your `/home` folder

[Download for 12.04](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/zsnes_1.510-2.2ubuntu5_i386.deb.html)

Install with

```
sudo dpkg -i zsnes_1.510-2.2ubuntu5_i386.deb
```

[Download for 14.04](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-14.04/ubuntu-universe-i386/zsnes_1.510+bz2-6_i386.deb.html)

Install with

```
sudo dpkg -i zsnes_1.510+bz2-6_i386.deb
```

[Download for 15.10](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-15.10/ubuntu-universe-i386/zsnes_1.510+bz2-8_i386.deb.html)

Install with

```
sudo dpkg -i zsnes_1.510+bz2-8_i386.deb
```

You may also need to enable 32 bit support if you have a 64 bit system, just run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: As I said before, I have no means of connecting my device to the internet. I can currently only use my desktop PC to download files. I could put Ubuntu on my PC, except that the PC is shared and quite slow. If I had Ubuntu with internet, the software center would be my first choice. It's also usefull to know this information offline.

Comment: Where did you say you had no Internet??? It is not in your question. What is your Ubuntu version also, so I can give you the right file.

Comment: I said it somewhere in the comment section. I know, why would I expect you to read all my replies? I shouldn't have. Sorry. I believe I have the latest version of Ubuntu MATE (15.10.1) on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B.

Comment: When I attemted to install the 15.10 version, it said it was the wrong architechture. I tried the sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386, but t said that "--add" wasn't recognized.